# How to display .cshtml content based on ActionLink in .NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

My Register.cshtml page contains both Patient and Doctor registration. I have written a script to check if the user is Patient then displays only  information relevant to patient and vice-versa.
If click on register patient then patient information only should insert into the database and the vice-versa for doctor registration.

Currently, If I register patient then it should not take specialization data into database because it is doctor's specific information.

Another problem is that, If I change the specialization or city value from drop down then it throws error:

> The ViewData item that has the key 'Specialization' is of type
>   'System.String' but must be of type 'IEnumerable'.
>
> Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: The ViewData item
>   that has the key 'Specialization' is of type 'System.String' but must
>   be of type 'IEnumerable'.
>
> Source Error:  @Html.DropDownListFor(x
>   => Model.Specialization, Model.Specializations, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control form-control-sm" })

Register.cshtml

```
model Aayumitra.Models.RegisterViewModel

<!-- Register Form -->
<div id="accounts-form">
    <div class="account-nav">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                <ul class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">

                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Login", "Login", "Account", null, new { @class = "mr-4" })</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Register", "Register", "Account", null, new { @class = "active" })</li>


                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        function getUrlVars() {
            var vars = {};
            var parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function (m, key, value) {
                vars[key] = value;
            });
            return vars;
        }

        var text = getUrlVars()["profile"];

        let profile;
        if (text) {
            if (text == 'doctor') {
                profile = 'doctor';
            }
            if (text == 'patient') {
                profile = 'patient';
            }
        } else {
            profile = 'patient';
        }
        $(document).ready(function () {
            if (profile === "doctor") {
                $(".doctor").show();
            }
            else {
                $(".doctor").hide();
            }
        });
    </script>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row py-5 border-top">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-img text-right">
                    <img src="~/Content/images/accounts.png" class="img-fluid" alt="Accounts Image">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-5">
                <div class="card">
                    <div id="form-card-header" class="card-header d-flex justify-content-between bg-white">
                        <h6>Join Aayumitra </h6>
                        <span class="float-right">Are you a Doctor? <span>@Html.ActionLink("register here", "register", "Account", new { profile = "doctor" }, null)</span>

                    </div>

                    <script>
    var formCardHeader = document.getElementById('form-card-header');

    if(profile == 'patient'){
        formCardHeader.innerHTML = `
        <h6>Join Aayumitra </h6>
                            <span class="float-right">Are you a Doctor? <span>@Html.ActionLink("register here", "register", "Account", new { profile="doctor"}, null)</</span>
        `
    }

    if (profile == 'doctor'){
        formCardHeader.innerHTML = `
        <h6 id="join-doctors">Join 1000+ doctors</h6>
                            <span id="not-doctor" class=""text-primary>@Html.ActionLink("Not a doctor?", "register", "Account", new { profile="patient"}, null)</span>
         `
                        }

                    </script>

                    @using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
                    {

                        <div class="card-body">
                            <form action="register.chtml?profile=doctor">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="FullName">First Name</label>
                                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName, new { @class = "form-control form-control-sm", placeholder = "First Name" })
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="FullName">Last Name</label>
                                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.LastName, new { @class = "form-control form-control-sm", placeholder = "First Name" })
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="email">Email</label>
                                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control form-control-sm", placeholder = "Email ID" })

                                </div>                                

                                <div class="form-group doctor">
                                    <label for="number">Specialization</label>
                                    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => Model.Specialization, Model.Specializations, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control form-control-sm", placeholder = "Specialization" })
                                </div>


                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="number">City</label>
                                    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => Model.City, Model.Cities, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control form-control-sm", placeholder = "City" })
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="number">Mobile Number</label>                                   

                                        <div class="col-md-8">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.MobileNumber, new { @class = "form-control form-control-sm", placeholder = "Mobile Number" })
                                            </div>
                                        </div>                                

                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="password">Create Password</label>
                                    @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "form-control form-control-sm", placeholder = "Password" })

                                </div>                                             

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="submit" value="Send" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">
                                </div>

                               </form>

                        </div>

                    }

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Register Form End -->
```

Controller

```
// GET: /Account/Register
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Register()
    {
        var model = new RegisterViewModel();
        List<SelectListItem> SpecialitiesList = GetSpecialities();
        List<SelectListItem> CitiesList = GetCities();
        model.Specializations = SpecialitiesList;
        model.Cities = GetCities();
        return View(model);
    }

    //
    // POST: /Account/Register
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {                
            var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email,FirstName=model.FirstName,LastName=model.LastName,City=model.City, IsDoctor = model.IsDoctor, NMC_Number = model.NMC_Number, Specialization = model.Specialization};

            var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false, rememberBrowser: false);
               return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            AddErrors(result);
        }         
        return View(model);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to solve it write two register action(doctor,Patient)that doctor and Patient have own view

Comment: Can you please provide me the solution based on situation. i am not sure how I am going to use 2 register action method.